# How to make the color of a div change permanently after it has been clicked in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs

[This is the grid that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Ixk.png)

[Once a square has been clicked, the color changes to red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2wNh.png) - This is done using active class

I would like the change to the background color of the div tag to remain permanent after the square has been clicked.

Code

**Board.js**

```
          {board.map((row, rowIdx) => (
            <div key={rowIdx} className="row">
              {row.map((cell, cellIdx) => (
                <div key={cellIdx} className="cell"></div>
               ))}
            </div>
              ))}
```

**Board.css**

```
.row {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.cell:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(134, 154, 189);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: seagreen;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;

}

.row :active {
  background-color: red;
}

.cell :active {              // Does not do anything
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a state, check the `style` prop in React docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once another square is clicked, the previosly clicked one does not remain active, you can do this by adding another class with your desired style, and using state to track the squares that have been clicked.

```
const [boardIndeces, setBoardIndeces] = useState(initArray(board));

const initArray = arr => {
  let rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let row = [];
    const currBoard = arr[i];
    for (let z = 0; z < currBoard.length; z++) {
      row[z] = false;
    }
    rows[i] = row;
  }
  return rows;
};

const onCellClick = (rowIdx, cellIdx) => {
  if (!(boardIndeces[rowIdx] && boardIndeces[rowIdx][cellIdx])) {
    boardIndeces[rowIdx][cellIdx] = true;
    setBoardIndeces([...boardIndeces]);
  }
};

{
  board.map((row, rowIdx) => (
    <div key={rowIdx}>
      {row.map((cell, cellIdx) => (
        <div
          key={cellIdx}
          className={
            boardIndeces[rowIdx].includes(cellIdx)
              ? 'your_active_class'
              : 'your_inactive_class'
          }
          onClick={() => onCellClick(rowIdx, cellIdx)}
        ></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked with one minor problem. Once a square is being clicked, the color of the entire row changes as opposed to just the color of the square being clicked. 

This is how I set up the classes in CSS:


.your_active_class .cell {
  background-color: orchid;
}


.your_inactive_class .cell  { 
  background-color: seagreen;
}

Comment: Seems like you need a multi-dimentional array, i modified my answer, can you try and give feedback?

Comment: I tried your solution but there is an error I am not able to resolve. I have created a live build of your second approach. You can find the live build and the error message [here](https://github.com/vishwa742/React-ticketing-app/blob/Stack/README.md). 

I made a few changes to your initial approach. I added a State variable (ifClicked) for cells. When BoardIndices[rowIdx] and ifClicked were true, I changed the class from 'cell' to 'new-cell' with the difference being bg-color but even here all the squares change colors. The build for this approach is: https://ticket-main-branch.netlify.app/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. The code for the side build is [here](https://github.com/vishwa742/React-ticketing-app/blob/Stack/src/components/board.js) and the main build is [here](https://github.com/vishwa742/React-ticketing-app/blob/master/src/components/board.js)

Comment: @VishwanathEzhil please check the edit ans, i create a function to initalize the multi-dimention array

Comment: I tried it out but clicking on any of the squares does not change anything. The state of the squares remain as "your_inactive _class". I created a separate branch with your code [here](https://github.com/vishwa742/React-ticketing-app/blob/Stack/src/components/board.js) and [css here](https://github.com/vishwa742/React-ticketing-app/blob/Stack/src/components/board.css). Could you have a look at that because I am not sure what is going wrong. 

I have removed all extra code so it is just the code for the grid.

Comment: @VishwanathEzhil since we changed the implementation we need to change the check, so instead of ``boardIndeces[rowIdx].includes(cellIdx) ? 'your_active_class' : 'your_inactive_class' }`` we use  ``boardIndeces[rowIdx][cellIdx] ? 'your_active_class' : 'your_inactive_class' }``

Answer (score 0):

You can use a checkbox if you don't want to use React

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color">
<label id="color-div" for="color">
    <!-- the div you want to change color -->
</label>
```

CSS

```
#color {
    display: none
}

#color:checked + #color-div { /* + in CSS is the sibling combinator */
   background-color: #fffff /* your background color */
}
```

What you're basically doing is making an invisible checkbox and toggling it with the label, when it's toggled you do the changes to the CSS
Remember the CSS combinators only work in elements after the HTML element it's being applied to